# regex matching not correctly in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, pattern-matching

I am trying to get specific string using regex in VB.NET.

Below is my code

The number 8538 is what I want.

However, I can only get full string, {"pushToken":"8538"} , which is not what I want.

Please tell my what I am doing wrong.

Thanks a lot.

```
Dim pushToken As String = "{""pushToken"":""8538""}"
Dim pattern = "{""pushToken"":""(.*)""}"
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(pushToken, pattern)
pushToken = match.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

`match.Value` would print the matched string only, in-order to print the chars which are at the group index 1, you need to call `match.Groups(1).Value`

```
pushToken = match.Groups(1).Value
```